# Docker Desktop for Mac Monterey: pop-up about privilege access to install networking components

Tags: macos, docker-desktop

I had Docker Desktop installed for Mac Catalina last year, but I haven't used it until today, a day after updating to Monterey (from Big Sur) (I'm on a Mac Intel) when I downloaded the latest Docker Desktop dmg file (~500MB), which had me drag the icon to the folder, which I then chose to replace the existing .app file... but when opening the file (in /Applications), I get this new pop-up:

[image]

I've tried to search what this is actually going to do, and I can't tell; I use Cisco AnyConnect VPN sometimes for a project, and I'm afraid there'll be a conflict... but ultimately, I don't know what exactly I'm giving access to or if it's actually necessary. I just want to try Docker with Laravel Sail.

I know macOS over the last several years (since Catalina really) has changed filesystem stuff *a lot* and I end up going down StackOverflow rabbit holes trying to get things to work, so I'm hoping someone else knows how this works or has made it work and can advise.